# Which approch is prefereable to implement programmable repeating notifications in Android?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager

my scenario is an application like Google Calendar / Google Keep. The user can create a simple events or repeating ones (time parameters can be chosen, the user can decide that the event can be every day, every month, or year ecc).

In this repeating events some (generally non-heavy) operation is performed and possibly a notification must be shown.

Which approch would you use?

1. An internal repeating job with a short interval that check every time what should be done (for example using WorkManager's PeriodicWorkRequest)
2. When a repeting job is created a specific job is scheduled to be executed at the expected time (for example using WorkManager's OneTimeWorkRequest). The specific job will also take care of scheduling the next repetition.
3. Other approch?

Also, is [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) appropriate for this?

Thanks

Comment: You can just use AlarmManager to wake up your app at specific time and show notification, so actually app doesn't need to be alive/be_in_RAM all the time.

Comment: @Raskilas From [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/): "WorkManager is intended for tasks that require a guarantee that the system will run them even if the app exits..." And also from [CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0): " WorkManager is currently in beta - when stable, it will be the recommended task scheduler on Android..." Besides the library to use I'm more interested in how to implement this, which is the best approach, architecture-wise.

Comment: What do you mean architecture-wise? If you won't intend to edit/maintain code for a long period then it doesn't matter with solution you would prefer, especially if it is non-heavy operations.

Comment: Of course I intend to maintain the code for a long period! I simply mean, given my requirements, would you use approach 1? approach 2? another one? How would you implement something that can be repeated, for example, once every mounth?

Comment: You ask about tool which will provide one of the whole features of your app, so it is not an architecture level. Looks like WorkManager provide good functionality, I didn't use it. And as for me, I would prefer JobScheduler/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor/AlarmManager because they are simple in mean that their behaviour well known and I know what my program will actually do, on other hand WorkManager may use JobScheduler or AlarmManager and I don't know why. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor/AlarmManager are reliably work since android 2.1 (I just didn't tested on more early devices).

Comment: My first question was the approch to use, regardless the library... But thanks for your suggestion